# Is it possible to create a brush chart with ChartJS?

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

Is it possible to create a brush chart as in this example using ChartJS and potentially plugins?

[image]

I’ve seen the zoom plugin https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/samples/drag/category.html which is almost like that but not quite.

Comment: Does it have to strictly be Chart.js?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't exactly what you want to do, but i've use [crosshair plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-crosshair) to select an area on a chart and then do a zoom in other charts. With this option is posible to select an area, but it can't be edit.

You need to overwrite `beforeZoom` callback method, so you get the range of you brush of the main chart, then return false to prevent zoom in the main chart. With the range, you'll be able to apply manualy a filter in the other charts.

Hope this help you c:

Comment: Thank you was searching for something like this to avoid making an entire custom char in D3.